# JScrollPane getX() returing wrong value ?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I wish to place a small Jframe right above the Button, on ActionPerformed

I directly tried to get the X (getX()) and Y(getY()) co-ordinates of the JScrollPane in which the button is added, but it always seems to return wrong co-coordinates

values returned by jScrollPane1.getLocation()

```
java.awt.Point[x=10,y=170]
```

The above values are same independent on where I place the JScrollPane on the screen.

This works if I remove the JScrollPane and directly try to get the Jpanels co-ordinates!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for example

```
private void showDialog() {
    if (canShow) {
        location = myButton.getLocationOnScreen();
        int x = location.x;
        int y = location.y;
        dialog.setLocation(x - 466, y - 514);
        if (!(dialog.isVisible())) {
            Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dialog.setVisible(true);
                    //setFocusButton();
                    //another method that moving Focus to the desired JComponent
                }
            };
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Harry Joy  :-) same/simlair amount as OP's `java.awt.Point[x=10,y=170]`

Answer (score 2):

This nice method will help you:

```
// Convert a coordinate relative to a component's bounds to screen coordinates
Point pt = new Point(component.getLocation());
SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(pt, component);
// pt is now the absolute screen coordinate of the component
```

Add: I didn't realise, but like *mKorbel* wrote, you can simply call

```
Point pt = component.getLocationOnScreen();
```

Comment: only this is maybe correct way, my bad, I can't found empty HDD space for SwingUtilities in my head,  my+1

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to spawn a new frame right above a given component, you want to get the screen coordinates of your component.

For this, you need to use the `getLocationOnScreen()` method of your component.

Here is a useful code snippet :

```
public void showFrameAboveCmp(Frame frame, Component cmp) {
    Dimension size = cmp.getSize();
    Point loc = cmp.getLocationOnScreen();
    Dimension frameSize = frame.getSize();
    loc.x += (size.width  - frameSize.width)/2;
    loc.y += (size.height - frameSize.height)/2;
    frame.setBounds(loc.x, loc.y, frameSize.width, frameSize.height);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```